# how to create an application which is trusted and grant it with admin privileges in Dot net

Tags: .net, uac

I have to create an application which needed to be opened without the UAC prompt. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Build a manifest and specify the `requestedExecutionLevel`

Answer (score 2):

UAC can be managed via a manifest file and setting the `requestedExecutionLevel`. There is a write-up on MSDN describing the process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a code access security policy that grants Full trust to the application.  I have done this for a Click Once applications where we needed to dynamically install x.509 certificates in to the IE certificate store.

Take a look at this link for info [enter link description here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/article.php/c19517)